# AMD: concurrent resources in module loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Let's say I have an application that load a module `myModule`. Said module needs some other resources to work (a template, for example), so it's neat that `myModule` cares to load the resources it needs. And it's quite easy, actually:

```
// main.js
require(["myModule"], function(myModule) {
    // ...
});

// myModule.js
define(["mustache", "text!myTemplate.mt"], function(mt, template) {
    // ...
});
```

However, what happens here is that *first* the module's script is loaded, *then* the script loads the resources it needs. What I'd like to achieve is to start to load `myModule` *and* `myTemplate` at the same moment in order to save time. I managed to do so by preloading the resources in `main.js`:

```
// main.js
require(["myModule", "text!myTemplate.mt"], function(myModule) {
    // ...
});
```

Is there a more elegant way to do so? Granted that I don't think there's a way to avoid that `main.js` must "know" `myModule`'s dependencies.

## Another problem

What if `myModule` doesn't *require* its resources, but rather they're *granted* to the module? Just like, "I require `myModule`, and it can use `template1` and `template3`".

I thought that configuring `require` with some `config` would do the trick:

```
// main.js
var templatesForMyModule = [...]
require.config({
    config: {
        myModule: templatesForMyModule
    }
});

// myModule.js
define(["module", "mustache"], function(module, mt) {
    var templates = module.config();
    // ...
});
```

The problem here is that I either pass the templates' paths - which would be loaded *after* `myModule` is loaded, thus leading to the initial problem - or the templates' contents, but that would imply that I have to load the templates *before* `myModule`, and that's another thing I'd like to avoid. Sadly, I can't do

```
require.config({
    config: {
        myModule: require(templatesForMyModule)
    }
});
```

and then, magically, retrieve the templates' contents inside `myModule.js`.

A solution would be: `myModule` returns a callback function that `main` calls after the resources are loaded, passing the resources to the callback. But that would change some of the code's workflow.

I still have the chance to use another module loader, so if another one is better suited for the task, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without statically declaring the dependencies in the main script.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite interesting. Let me try to address the first problem:

Let's say your `myModule.js` is:

```
define(["mustache", "text!myTemplate.mt"], function(mt, template) {
    // ... A LOT OF CODE
    // ... THAT WILL TAKE
    // ... SOME TIME TO LOAD
});
```

So, `mustache` and `myTemplate.mt` will have to wait for `myModule.js` to be loaded and parsed. This is your problem.

Why don't you rearrange the code as:

```
// myModule.js
define(["myModuleMain", "mustache", "text!myTemplate.mt"], function(myModuleMain, mt, template) {
    return myModuleMain;
});

// myModuleMain.js
define(["mustache", "text!myTemplate.mt"], function(mt, template) {
    // ... A LOT OF CODE
    // ... THAT WILL TAKE
    // ... SOME TIME TO LOAD
});
```

Now `myModule.js` is small and will load quickly. Additionally, it will start loading its dependencies, i.e. mustache, the template and the bulk of your code in parallel, which is the effect you need.

Looking at it it seems hackish; the new `myModule.js` needs to know the dependencies of `myModuleMain.js`, the dependencies have to be kept synchronized and it returns the same object. At least dependencies are more localized this way, in contrast to requiring everything from `main.js`.

If you wanted to be more fancy, you could add an auto-generation step in your build or your server that will produce the "new" `myModule.js` and `myModuleMain.js` from the original `myModule.js`.

---

Another option would be to use the `bundles` configuration option ([ref](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles)) with some work on the project's build. An outline of this solution is:

1. Tweak the build scripts to produce a bundle out of `myModule.js`, mustache, the template; let the produced JS be called `myModuleBundle.js`.
2. Configure the bundle:

   ```
   bundles: {
       "myModuleBundle": ["myModule", "mustache", "text!myTemplate.mt"],
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Now requiring `myModule` will load the entire bundle in parallel.

This is obviously flawed if mustache is also required by other modules, as it will load it multiple times. However, if mustache is required at a global level, it wouldn't harm to require it from main or even using the `deps` configuration option ([ref](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps)).

Comment: Interesting approach. The first solution is indeed hackish, and introduces another HTTP request. Its impact is to be considered, but above all at the moment we can't use any effective builder for that, so the result would definitely be less maintainable.

Comment: The `bundles` solution looks very promising (I didn't know about that, I see it was introduced only this January). What worries me is that, if I'm not mistaken, `myModule` must *statically* declare its dependencies, whereas the resources it can access to may be *dynamic*. Is there any way to address all the resources in the bundle the module it's been included into (I can see a workaround for this though)? Secondarily, are you sure that `mustache` would be loaded many times? This sounds odd to me, as it would kind of defeat one of the purposes of AMD loaders.

Comment: (By the way, I'm aware of your lazy loader plugin for Require.js.)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "`myModule` must statically declare its dependencies, whereas the resources it can access to may be dynamic"...

Comment: About mustache being loaded may times - clarification: What I mean is that besides `myModule` there will probably be `myOtherModule` with similar structure and requirement on mustache. If you make 2 bundles and include mustache in each of them, because it is listed in the dependencies of `myModule` *AND* `myOtherModule`, then its code will be downloaded twice. The mustache module will be declared once in the AMD environment, what I mean is that the download time will be greater.

Comment: I mean this: how can `myModule` access the resources (and the modules) loaded in its bundle? Is there an easy way if `myModule` doesn't "know" the whole bundle?

Comment: Ah, so you want, so to say, module discovery: if `myModule` lives besides `a.js`, `b.js`, then it should depend on `["./a", "./b"]`; if `c.js` is added, then it should depend on `["./a", "./b", "./c"]`. If so, I do not think it is doable with plain RequireJS. You will have to use either a server-side or a build-time solution.

Comment: That's what I thought. But I can play this card: if I define a bundle in an array `bundleList`, then I can pass `bundleList` as the module's `config` (as defined in `require.config`); then, in `myModule`, I can retrieve `bundleList` and require the resources, which are either already loaded or in the process of being loaded, thus optimizing loading times. Verbose? Yes. Complex? Yes. Effective? Hopefully yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, after some tests, this isn't what I was looking for, as `bundles` is useful for building tools and doesn't start fetching the modules if they're not explicitly declared as dependencies somewhere.